# Como validar um hash wmsAuthSign no php?

Tags: php, segurança, validação, lógica, md5

Tenho o seguinte código que cria um *hash* de segurança para a autenticação em servidores de mídia, gostaria de saber como ele poderia ser validado no próprio php, os servidores de mídia devem usar alguma logica para isso, e é isso o que desejo, um código que faça o mesmo em php.

Creio que a maior dificuldade seja com o `gmdate` que muda a cara acesso a função de geração do *hash* de segurança, como o *hash* é passado via `md5`, não tem como obter o `gmdate` para uma comparação, por segurança é claro, então, o que poderia ser feito para se criar uma nova função de validação do *hash* `wmsAuthSign`?

O código de geração do [wmsAuthSign](https://github.com/WMSPanel/paywall-code-samples-wmsauth/blob/master/php/jwpayer-rtmp-hls.php):

```
$today = gmdate("n/j/Y g:i:s A");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$key = "defaultpassword";
$validminutes = 20;
$str2hash = $ip . $key . $today . $validminutes;
$md5raw = md5($str2hash, true);
$base64hash = base64_encode($md5raw);
$urlsignature = "server_time=" . $today ."&hash_value=" . $base64hash. "&validminutes=$validminutes";
$base64urlsignature = base64_encode($urlsignature);
wmsAuthSign=<?php echo $base64urlsignature;?>
```

Em resumo, eu crio o meu próprio *hash*, mas não sei validar no php.

Comment: Caso alguém tenha uma resposta que exija a modificação do código acima, sintam-se livres para postar, o código modificado com a resposta, desde que isso não resulte em uma perda de segurança nesta função.

Answer (score 2):

```
base64_decode($urlsignature);
$dados = explode($urlsignature,"&");
$validar = [];
foreach($dados as $k=>$v){
    //converte a url em array
    $temp = explode($v,"=");
    $key = $temp[0];
    unset($temp[0]);
    if(count($temp)>1){
        $value = implode($temp,"=");
    }
    else{
        $value = $temp[1];
    }
    $validar[$key] = $value;
}

// O array Validar terá todos os seus dados, mas saiba que uma vez que você converter para md5, o mesmo não poderá ser "desconvertido" (na verdade é pra isso mesmo que o md5 serve kkkkk)
```